# Span tags disappear from source code - Use Select2 instead

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have the following HTML code:

```
<select class = "form-control">
    <option value="0">sometext</option>
    <option value="1">sometext <span class="myclass1">someothertext</span></option>
    <option value="2">sometext <span class="myclass2">someothertext</span></option>
    <option value="3">sometext <span class="myclass3">someothertext</span></option>
    <option value="4">sometext <span class="myclass4">someothertext</span></option>
</select>
```

When I use the "inspect element" in browser (Chrome & Mozilla) the span tag is missing, but the `someothertext` is there without the span. If I check the source code in a new page, using right click -> view source page, the span tag is there.

I have a JQuery code which manipulate span tags with specific classes. Every span outside of the select tag works, expect these who missing.

**Update my question using the Select2 Jquery plugin from the "duplicate" answer.**
I downloaded the Select2 jquery plugin and try to use this to include span tags.

```
<select id="selectid">
        <option value="0" data-foo="">sometext</option>
        <option value="1" data-foo="myclass1">sometext</option>
        <option value="2" data-foo="myclass2">sometext</option>
        <option value="3" data-foo="myclass3">sometext</option>
        <option value="4" data-foo="myclass4">sometext</option>
</select>

<script src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/select2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function format(state) {
    var originalOption = state.element;

    return state.text + " " + "<span class='"+ $(originalOption).data('foo') + "'>" + $(originalOption).data('foo') +  "</span>" ;
   }
   $("#selectid").select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    formatResult: format,
    formatSelection: format,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
   });
 </script>

<script src="/static/js/mycustomjs.js"></script>
```

The plugin changes the source code to div and include span tags in the options. But even if I call mycustom js after the select2.js, still it doesn't seems to work. In every other span, it works.

Comment: That's probably because that's invalid HTML and option elements can't contain span elements.

Comment: @j08691 Didn't know that. Is there any way to split the text inside the option so I can manipulate only the second text with JQuery code?

Comment: You could use a unique character as a delimiter. Or if the options will only contain two words, split it on the space.

Comment: I have updated my question using information of the "duplicate" question